# Go-to method for securing multiple NM-B runs

Tags: electrical

.Hey, all!

Looking for code compliant ideas for how to secure 3-4 new NM-B runs in the basement. I'm a big fan of bridle rings for low voltage. Are bridle rings kosher for 120 or 240v? Maybe a large handy strap?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit of an Authority Having Jurisdiction issue. There's no section that that says no bridle rings. Most inspectors are pretty lenient when it comes to data cable support, but when dealing with power most will be quick to jump to "not UL approved".

Comment: Ah, alright, thanks! Figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 4):

For power wiring you want something that maintains cable spacing.

[image: Multi-cable-clip]

*Image Source https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.homedepot-static.com%2FproductImages%2F333babb0-197a-42b2-8949-80cce962f853%2Fsvn%2Fred-gardner-bender-electrical-staples-mcs-100w-64_1000.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=c4424e22a3faa4c0e333ea314fa7225574d99d904947155f5ab0ab6f2c840f16&ipo=images no endorsement implied*

Or simply use a bit more space and single cable staples. **Cooling** matters to power cables, unlike network or telephone cables, so large bundles are to be avoided (or you get into derating and need HUGE wire size increases as a result.)

Comment: Wow, those are cool! I'll pick some up. Thank you!This must be a relatively recent thing, or someone forgot to tell the builder who built our house. 1999 construction. There's probably a dozen Romex zip-tied together as a bundle to staples traversing most of the basement before splitting off into separate runs. Looks sketchy as hell.

Comment: @Zoinks whoever zip-tied bundles of Romex probably has not read NEC 3101.5(B)(3)(a) [TLDR: no more than 4 circuits in the same grouping for thermal reasons].   Those need spacing.  Also if they stapled one Romex and zip-tied the rest to the first Romex, that's a violation, you're not allowed to hang things off electrical cables and conduits.

Comment: Hah! Well. Is this a relative recent code change in the past 25 years? I don't see how it could have passed otherwise. I'm counting about a dozen 14-2s, some 12-2s, and for part of the run a 10-something (dryer), all ziptied. They do come apart a bit between the zip ties, but they are mostly bundled